# Location of the close button on the StackExchange popup menu

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, stack-exchange

I'm not used to closing windows by clicking in the bottom right, where the *StackExchange* pop-up menu has its *close* link. Wouldn't an "X" button on the top right make more sense? It would also follow Fitts' law.

Comment: When referring to Fitts, you should ask for the Mac position of the close button, being the top left (much closer to where the mouse is after clicking to open the menu)... ;-)

Comment: +1 on this, it's very counter-intuitive in it's current location...also a click outside the popup should close it IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that it is more natural on the top.  Also, and this maybe horrible - but how about a loose OS-detect to determine whether the closer should be on the right or left side?  Macs get a closer on the left, like they're used to from their OS interface, whereas Windows users get the familiar right-hand closer.

The OS detect doesn't have to get crazy... if you can detect it with a shallow check, use the findings, otherwise default to the right.

Answer (score 0):

The close button would be inconsequential if the dialog were moved down a bit.  See [The StackExchange menu is too high](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75176/the-stackexchange-menu-is-too-high).