# The StackExchange menu is too high

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, stack-exchange-button

I think the StackExchange menu should open *below* where I clicked, so if I click again, it closes instead of going to the StackExchange site. The way it works now violates convention for drop-down menus.

**Edit**

Here's an image showing the menu I'm talking about:

[image]

The cursor is hovering right over the link, but I believe the whole menu should be moved down a few pixels so that clicking again will close the menu.

**Edit2**

Thanks to Jeff M for making some mockups:

[image: Like this]

[image: Not like this]

Comment: Which menu do you mean? The collider thingy?

Comment: @Pekka, see my edit.

Comment: why don't you do a quick mockup/psd of what you are thinking of?

Comment: @andrew: I can't edit the question but here's some visual aids: [like this](http://i.imgur.com/jMwiv.png) [not like this](http://i.imgur.com/5KxVW.png)

Comment: @Jeff, thanks for making these...I'll add the links to my question.

Comment: The menu is too damn high!

Comment: someone take a look at this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75989/move-the-stack-exchange-link-to-the-right

Comment: @andrewk, slightly different solution to address the same problem. I like moving the whole thing down better because it fits the way I think menus should work, but your idea would work too.

Comment: Oh the irony, the user-info dropdown is just right and yet the Stack Exchange dropdown is still too high.  :)

Comment: It is not too high anymore! Rejoice.

Comment: @Jeff, *rejoicing* !!!

Answer (score -8):

To close this menu:

- click *anywhere* on the screen
- click *anywhere* on the dark close border at the bottom
- press the <kbd>esc</kbd> key

I'm not sure I agree that web "menus" need to follow the Windows 3.1 GUI design guide.

Comment: I only brought this up because I've clicked that StackExchange link like three times by accident. I think my eyes had already moved on to something else on the screen when I clicked and I was suddenly on a new page. Maybe it's just me, though.

Comment: Perhaps, but this violates the foremost guiding principle of UI design: don't make me think! I've accidentally opened SE.com at least a dozen times... and got auto-logged in... so I have to log out, and then, *finally*, get back to what I was doing.

Comment: if you can, apply a `top:30px;` style to the #seWrapper div. http://i.imgur.com/0SGL9.png

Comment: Can we take a look at this again?  The new user-info dropdown is now positioned in a way that Dan (and everyone here) was requesting for the Stack Exchange menu.  This isn't really an impossible change is it?

Comment: -1 This behaves more like a popup than a menu.  Menus can be closed by clicking the same thing that opened them.  This popup cannot.  Even if we ignore all UI design it is still inconsistent with the way the user menu works on the same page.