# [pic] Move the Stack Exchange link in the global inbox to the right

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, hyperlinks, global-inbox, design

This has kind of [been tried before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75176/the-stackexchange-menu-is-too-high), but not quite.

I suggest that the Stack Exchange link in the global inbox (AKA MultiCollider) be shoved to the right. I've mis-clicked like 30 times and have ended up on `stackexchange.com` many times. *Something similar will do* fine.

> Take a look at my mockup. It's worth more than a thousand words.

[image: before and after layouts]

Comment: Why would moving it prevent misclicks?

Comment: umm have you seen the pic? the link is to the right.. your mouse wont be there by default.

Comment: I have absolutely no problem with the current layout. What do you keep clicking on?