# Feature Request: moving the "Stack Exchange" link on the "StackExchange" menu?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, stack-exchange-button

The StackExchange button in the upper-left corner of all of the sites is a menu. It has the little down-arrow next to it, and after clicking, a menu-like thing pops up.

When I want to dismiss the box, I do what seems natural, which is clicking again. Just like any other menu - you click File, scan the items, and then click File again (without moving your mouse) to dismiss the menu.

However, when you click this popup, now the button under your mouse is a link taking you to "stackexchange.com". This is frustrating! Now I have to move my mouse to dismiss that box, but I'm never really thinking about it, so I always end up at stackexchange.com.

Could we fix the UI? Maybe make that link 10px lower so that your mouse isn't hovering over it when you click the StackExchange button? Or something?

Edit: It looks like this has been done. Thanks stackoverflow team!

Comment: The normal behaviour is to hit ESC

Comment: NO! The normal behaviour is to click somewhere else that is inocuous! Or hit Caps Lock.

Comment: I have had this exact thing happen countless times. Clicking again is definitely the normal behavior for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[pic\] Move the Stack Exchange link in the global inbox to the right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75989/pic-move-the-stack-exchange-link-in-the-global-inbox-to-the-right)

Comment: Ah, I missed the other iterations of this question, including: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75176/the-stackexchange-menu-is-too-high

Comment: Interestingly, the arrow to the right of the StackExchange button and to the left of the username are the same affordance - a drop-down menu. The username-arrow behaves as expected (returning you to the initial page state when clicked again) whereas the StackExchange arrow's FSM takes you to a different page!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that it can be a pain sometimes that if you click on it (the stackexchange link) to open the popup *before* the javascript has finished loading, it sends you off to the stackexchange site instead of showing the popup which leaves the page functional when javascript isn't enabled or available.

This makes sense of course because the URL from the link is overridden by the javascript...this does seem to happen more often than I would like (too impatient I guess)...may also be more prevalent on mobile devices with slower connections etc